# Overlay position error when using angular material mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

Getting error:

> ERROR TypeError: this._overlay.position(...).flexibleConnectedTo(...).withTransformOriginOn is not a function
>       at MatMenuTrigger.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/menu.es5.js.MatMenuTrigger._getOverlayConfig (menu.es5.js:1320)

```
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Angular material version 6.4.7, cdk version 6.0.1 and cli version 6.1.3

Comment: What is the version of the @angular/cdk dependency?

Comment: cdk version is 6.0.1

Comment: @Ploppy Thanks for the hint. updating @angular/cdk to 6.4.7 worked!

Comment: Yep it was what I thought. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your @angular/cdk version is not aligned with the @angular/material version.

In your case, they both should be at version 6.4.7

In the future, make sure to update your app with the [ng update](https://angular.io/cli/update) command, it takes care of those things for you.